# git: automate tempory branch change on remote so you can push to a non-bare repo

Tags: git, push, branch

As you may know, it's generally unsafe to push to a remote non-bare repo if the branch is currently checked out, e.g.:

```
$ git push -f origin
Enumerating objects: 13, done.
Counting objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 1013 bytes | 1013.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/ptr-type
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: 
remote: You can set the 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable
remote: to 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: other way.
remote: 
remote: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
```

However, on the remote if you switch to another branch, then re-run the push, it will succeed. You can then change back to the branch you just pushed, and all is well.

My question is: is there a way to automate this from the remote side, without having to manually change branch on the remote. Ideally using only git (and not an extra `ssh` invocation).

Note that "push to deploy" won't work for me, as the commits will be different (only in that I've signed them).

Thanks